# Add logo in margin note?

Tags: memoir

How do i include a logo in my reports margin note on multiple pages? Like, one logo from page 10-20 and another logo from page 20-30?

Comment: \marginpar{\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{...}} or do you mean on every page?

Comment: Use the package `marginnote` and its `\marginnote` command. It's quite straight forward

Comment: @JohnKormylo. That is the problem. It is on multiple pages. like,  one logo from page 10-20, another logo from page 20-30 etc..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps this provides some clue, using `everypage` package and the `marginnote` package.

As stated in `everypage` documentation, specific setups on particular pages must be achieved with conditionals, i.e. queries on the page number, for example.

Since there is no further information on the particular vertical placement of the logo(s), I added no vertical shift.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\AddEverypageHook{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{page}}{9}{%
    \ifnumless{\value{page}}{21}{%
      \marginnote{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}}%
    }{%
      \ifnumgreater{\value{page}}{20}{%
        \ifnumless{\value{page}}{31}{%
          \marginnote{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}}%
        }{}%
      }{}%
    }}{}%
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[160]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]